# Could not load AnnotationConfiguration hibernate ,when internet is not connected

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate

i am using hibernate 4.0 and mysql 5.6 with eclipse luna(v4.4.1),
i am using hibernate annotations in my project. 
When i make changes to any table of DB, I always generate hibernate annotations automatically via eclipse hibernate configurations. 
my question is that:
when i do not connect internet and want to generate hibernate annotations i get this ERROR :  [Classpath]: Could not load AnnotationConfiguration (screen shot also attached) and when i connect to internet i do not face this error.
is this bug or feature ?? if this is feature then how can i generate hibernate annotations offline?
thanks!
[image]

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">myroot</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.72.128:3306/hesco</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myroot</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting all the dtds needed in local.

```
http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
```

In fact your url in the hibernate confil file should be the cause :

192.168.72.128

Try localhost if it's your ip adress.

Comment: thanks man you have save my day, my question is that how and where(location) can i put dtd in my project ?
btw 192.168.72.128 is my server machine ip which is working fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Any idea why is this behaviour happening?

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Xavier Bouclet who guide me about dtd problem, I did google it and find my solution from this [link](http://www.journaldev.com/2959/how-to-configure-hibernate-cfg-xml-to-work-offline)

i put below `DOCTYPE` to my **hibernate.cfg.xml** file and now i can work offline

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">myroot</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.72.128:3306/hesco</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myroot</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```